# Intercept action controller with arguments in mvc 5 with lightinject interception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, aop, asp.net-mvc-5.2, light-inject

I'm not able to intercept a controller action with arguments.
I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5 with LightInject and LightInject.Interception.
I receive the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.CustomModelBinderAttribute[]'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.CustomModelBinderAttribute[]'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace: 


[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.CustomModelBinderAttribute[]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.GetBinderFromAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider element, Action`1 errorAction) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedParameterBindingInfo.get_Binder() +102
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetModelBinder(ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

My code is (I do not insert views because are meaningless):

```
// Global.asax
namespace TestMVCInjection
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;
    using LightInject;
    using LightInject.Interception;

    using TestMVCInjection.Controllers;

    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        public void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            //FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            RegisterLightInject();
        }

        private void RegisterLightInject()
        {
            var container = new ServiceContainer();
            container.RegisterControllers();
            container.EnableMvc();
            container.Intercept((ServiceRegistration c) => c.ServiceType == typeof(HomeController), (IServiceFactory c) => (IInterceptor)new DebugInterceptor());
        }
    }

    public class DebugInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public object Invoke(IInvocationInfo invocationInfo)
        {
            object returnValue = null;
            // Verifico se devo intercettare il metodo
            var mi = invocationInfo.Method;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff \"GMT\"zzz");
            string method = $"{invocationInfo.Method.DeclaringType.Name}.{invocationInfo.Method.Name}";
            try
            {
                var parNames = invocationInfo.Method.GetParameters().Select(d => $"{d.Name}: {d.ParameterType}").ToList();
                var parValues = invocationInfo.Arguments.Select(c => $"{c}").ToList();
                string parameters = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, parNames.Select((n, i) => $"{parNames[i]} = {parValues[i]}"));
                string message = $"{nameof(timestamp).ToUpper()}={timestamp}{Environment.NewLine}{nameof(method).ToUpper()}={method}{Environment.NewLine}{nameof(parameters).ToUpper()}{Environment.NewLine}{parameters}";
                Debug.WriteLine(message);
                returnValue = invocationInfo.Proceed();
                message = $"TOOK {nameof(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)} = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} for returning {returnValue} for method {method}";
                Debug.WriteLine(message);
                return returnValue;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                string message = $"Took {nameof(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)} = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} for throwing an exception method {method}";
                Debug.WriteLine(message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller is:

```
namespace TestMVCInjection.Controllers
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public virtual ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("-----> INDEX START <-----");
            var response = View((object)id);
            Debug.WriteLine("-----> INDEX END <-----");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can direct me to the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted an issue on github repository.
It has been corrected some hours ago (LightInject.Inteception 2.0.1).